# Luminus- accessing data from a REST API route in a selmer template

Tags: clojure, luminus, reitit, selmer

I would like to make a Luminus app that provides a REST API and serves data from that API in Selmer templates. However, I can't figure out how to get the routing to work.

For example, if you create a luminus template using the command `lein new luminus consume_rest +reitit +swagger`, you'll get selmer templates under `home-routes` and the REST API under `service-routes`. I would like to include data provided by endpoints under `service routes` within the templates in `home-routes`.

Does anyone have a suggested way on how to architect this, or an example of an application that does so? Every project I`ve seen with a REST API is a SPA using clojurescript, which call the REST API with AJAX.

Comment: Would you clarify why you want this?  Typically, the data returned by `home-routes` and selmer is HTML and is for human consumption.  Typically, the data returned by an API under `service-routes` is meant for machine consumption and it usually will be JSON or EDN or XML or some such format.  Mixing the two seems like a bad architectural choice.

Comment: I'd like to have an API so that I have the flexibility to swap out selmer or add mobile clients in the future.

Comment: You could make another namespace for defining all clojure apis, define similar routes in service-routes and home-routes and call the clojure apis from routes handlers. Data will be consistent, and in home-routes handler you can pass this data into relevant template. Have you tried structuring like this?